# Paramagnetic/diamagnetic fluid separation

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, magnetic-fields, liquid-state

Is it possible to separate fluids or at least alter their relative concentrations in the presence of a magnetic field if one fluid is diamagnetic and the other paramagnetic?
If so by how much? Are there any studies or data on this? How could this effect be calculated?